# AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth While Custom Binding a UIFont to a UILabel

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

Using Xamarin and mvvmcross, I created a custom bind to give a label a font. Then I used a converter to convert a string to a font.

Custom Bind:

```
public class LabelFontTargetBinding : MvxTargetBinding
{
    public LabelFontTargetBinding(UILabel label)
        : base(label)
    {
    }

    public override void SetValue(object value)
    {
        Label.Font = (UIFont) value;
    }
}
```

Converter:

```
public class StringToFontConverter : MvxValueConverter<string, UIFont>
{
    protected override UIFont Convert(string value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return UIFont.FromName(value, 80.0f);
    }
}
```

This works fine except that it overrides the `label.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;`. In this case, the font size will always be `80.0f`.

Is there another way to bind a UIFont to a UILabel without overriding (overwriting?) the AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth?

Comment: What do you mean by 'overrides' here? If you set `label.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;` in the binding, does it not work? (Sorry if that's a stupid question - don't have a Mac with me right now)

Comment: Probably more like 'overwrites' the font size. This is more of an assumption from my results. Prior to refactoring my code, the font size would change (no custom binding). Now, the font size is whatever size I put in the converter.